# Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a small problem in my where clause in the linq expression below. If I put the number 3 instead of department.Id I get the desired result but when I use department.Id I get nothing in the resultset.

I also want to get a count for the number of filters for that filter name using the query again using distinct.

```
var dept = Page.RouteData.Values["department"];
var department = (from d in db.Departments 
                  where d.Name.Replace(" ", "-") == dept 
                  select new {d.Id, d.Name}).FirstOrDefault();


var query = from p in db.Products
            join f in db.ProductFilters on p.Id equals f.ProductId into filters
            from x in filters.Where(x => x.Product.DepartmentId == department.Id 
            /* if == 3 it works */)                            
            select new { x.Name, x.Id };
```

Comment: Have you checked that the department instance is as you think it should be after the first linq statement - ie has an `Id == 3`?

Comment: I feel pretty silly now. I was using the wrong department in the url RouteData. it works now. But now thats fixed and it works do you know how i can get a count for my filters in there groups e.g Under Brands name would be a brand and that would have filters with a count next of how many brands are in that filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoted to answer from comments:

Have you checked that the department instance is as you think it should be after the first linq statement - ie has an `Id == 3`?

Comment: I found the problem i was using the wrong RouteData Value sorry everyone. can you answer my second question in my comments

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is not finding any valid `department` and is therefore returning `default` which most probably means that `departmend.Id == 0`.